# How do I prevent RSC from rerender and call the database

Tags: next.js13

I'm building an e-commerce store for a friend using NEXTJS13 APP ROUTER and I faced the following issue: I have a rsc that calls a database directly (Example-1) and gets a list of categories then passes them to client components to render them and handle the events (example 2).

I delayed the rsc with 10s to understand how it works and I found whenever I check a checkbox it takes 10s to reflect and everything freezes.

My question is why does the rsc get re-rendered again even if nothing happens inside of it? (does that means that the database gets called at each render? I'm planning to deploy into serverless I don't want to get a 1M$ bill)

example 1

```
import db from "~/lib/db";
import CategoriesItems from "./categories-items";

const Categories = async () => {
  const categories = await db.category.findMany();

  // everytime i check a checkbox "Rerendered" gets printed to the console
  console.log("Rerendered")

  await new Promise((resolver) => setTimeout(resolver, 10000));

  return <CategoriesItems categories={categories} />;
};

export default Categories;
```

example 2

```
"use client";

import { Category } from "@prisma/client";
import { Label } from "../ui/label";
import { Checkbox } from "../ui/checkbox";
import { useRouter, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useMemo } from "react";

interface CategoriesItemsProps {
  categories: Category[];
}

const CategoriesItems: React.FC<CategoriesItemsProps> = ({ categories }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  const rawSearchParamsCategories = useMemo(() => {
    return searchParams.get("categories");
  }, [searchParams.get("categories")]);

  const searchParamsCategories = useMemo(() => {
    return rawSearchParamsCategories
      ? rawSearchParamsCategories.split(",").filter((v) => v)
      : [];
  }, [rawSearchParamsCategories]);

  const checkIt = (categoryName: string) => {
    let newSearchParamsCategories = searchParamsCategories;
    const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);

    if (searchParamsCategories.includes(categoryName)) {
      newSearchParamsCategories = newSearchParamsCategories.filter(
        (category) => category !== categoryName
      );
    } else {
      newSearchParamsCategories.push(categoryName);
    }

    urlSearchParams.set("categories", newSearchParamsCategories.join(","));

    router.push(`?${urlSearchParams.toString()}`);
  };

  return (
    <ul className="flex flex-col gap-4">
      {categories.map((category) => (
        <li key={category.id} className="flex items-center gap-2">
          <Checkbox
            checked={!!searchParamsCategories.includes(category.name)}
            id={category.id}
            onClick={() => checkIt(category.name)}
          />
          <Label htmlFor={category.id}>{category.name}</Label>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default CategoriesItems;
```

More details

I have a products page with a sidebar and a grid on the right the sidebar contains filter and that filter contains a rsc that has a db call to get all categories then it passes those categories to a client component to render them with a checkbox for each one, When you click the checkbox the searchparams changes and adds a category to is it looks like this ?categories=one,two,three.

When ever I check a checkbox the rsc with the db call gets re-rendered again and that calls a the db again and re-renders the new categories and that's not what I want, This will cause massive db calls and I don't want that, What I want is when I check a checkbox the searchparams changes so that the products grid can get that and get the products based on the selected categories.

One more issue is, when I do click the next page on the pagination it waits for the categories to to be fetched (the pagination changes the search params), Which is not necessary at all.

Please if you have any suggestions, tell me

I tried Parallel routes, did not solve it

I want when I check or browse pages the categories db call does not get executed